# Wifi list is empty after latest update (yesterday)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

Using Ubuntu 14.04 on MacBookAir6-2

```
~$ nmcli device
DEVICE     TYPE              STATE        
eth0       802-3-ethernet    connected    
A0:F4:50:DB:EA:91 bluetooth         disconnected 
64:CC:2E:5A:17:B3 bluetooth         disconnected 
wlan0      802-11-wireless   unmanaged
```

As you can see, `wlan0` is `unmanaged`.

The **Wi-Fi Networks** list display in the drop down menu of the network button in the system bar (top-right of the screen), says:
*device not managed*

I tried everything I found by searching and none of it helped.

How can I fix this?

Comment: And, the wifi network was OK till the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

I recovered my wifi connection by doing following:

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

then comment lines about interface "wan0", like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet dhcp
#    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#sudo systemctl enable wpa_supplicant.service
```

above is all the content in the file.

I don't know why, it just works.